# Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte...invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm building a web scraper using BeautifulSoup on Python 3.3

However I get a problem which prevents me from getting a valid strin* that I can use with BeautifulSoup. That is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 7047: invalid continuation byte
```

I know there are dozens of similar questions but I haven't so far found a method that can help me to diagnose what's wrong with the following code:

```
import urllib.request
URL = "<url>" # sorry, I cannot show the url for privacy reasons, but it's a normal html document
page = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
page = page.read().decode("utf-8") # from bytes to <source encodings>
```

As I guessed I notice *this error occurs only with some URLS and not with others*. Even with this same error I wasn't having this error until yesterday. Then today I run the program again and the error popped up..

Any clue on how to diagnose the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* decode the response. First of all, you are incorrectly assuming the response is UTF-8 encoded (it is not, as the error shows), but more importantly, BeautifulSoup will detect the encoding *for you*. See the [*Encodings* section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) of the BeautifulSoup documentation.

Pass a byte string to BeautifulSoup and it'll use any `<meta>` header proclaiming the correct encoding, or do great job of autodetecting the encoding for you.

In the event that auto-detection fails, you can always fall back to the server-provided encoding:

```
encoding = page.info().get_charset()
page = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
if encoding is not None and soup.original_encoding != encoding:
    print('Server and BeautifulSoup disagree')
    print('Content-type states it is {}, BS4 states thinks it is {}'.format(encoding, soup.original_encoding)
    print('Forcing encoding to server-supplied codec')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, from_encoding=encoding)
```

This still leaves the actual decoding to BeautifulSoup, but if the server included a `charset` parameter in the `Content-Type` header then the above assumes that the server is correctly configured and forces BeautifulSoup to use that encoding.